# How to do Without Replacement In Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am doing a program where 3 numbers from 1-5 are randomly generated.  I want it so that when a number is generated, it can't be generated again.

Like so I can't get 121, only something like 134

Answer (score 5):

You can put all the possible numbers into a collection.
Then you randomly 'pop' them out one-by-one.

This method is similar to [Knuth's shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which is more efficient than
the naive method of checking-whether-a-number-has-been-generated-or-not,
because the later might not terminate.

Answer (score 1):

1.convert 3 numbers to single 3-digit number.

2.collect all created numbers in some collection (Set should be ok)

3.if the new number is already in the collection - generate it again, till it's totally new

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int digits = 5;
    final int toGenarate = 10;
    Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<Integer>();

    int generated = 0;
    while (generated < toGenarate) {
        int number = generate(digits);
        while (used.contains(number)) {
            number = generate(digits);
        }
        used.add(number);
        generated++;
        System.out.println(number);
    }

}

private static int generate(final int digits) {
    final Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(digits) * 100 + r.nextInt(digits) * 10 + r.nextInt(digits);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the set of possible results is so small, it is perfectly reasonable to enumerate them all, put them in a data structure, and then randomly select and remove them.  The enumeration is also fairly simple: you are finding the Cartesian product of the sets of possible values, and there are a number of well-known ways to accomplish that, just type it in the search box.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want  3 random numbers, psuedo code :

1. declare 3 variables r1, r2 and r3
2. r1 = getRandom(1, 5). getRandom is a function that gets a random number between param 1 and 2 inclusive
3. r2 = getRandom(1, 5)
4. while r2 = r1 go to step 3
5. r3 = getRandom(1, 5)
6. while r1 = r3 or r2 = r3 go to step 5

If you had more than 3 numbers could use an outer loop and a Map

I see it is in java now

```
import  java.util.*;
public class RandomSet{

    public static void main(String[]a){


        java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random ();
        final int high = 5, low = 1, ll = low - 1;
        int r1 = ll,r2 = ll,r3 = ll;

        r1 = rnd.nextInt(high - 1) + low;
        while(r2 == (ll) || r2 == r1){
            r2 = rnd.nextInt(high - 1) + low;
        }
        while(r3 == (ll) || r3 == r1 || r2 == r3){
            r3 = rnd.nextInt(high - 1) + low;
        }
        System.out.println("r1 " + r1 + "; r2 " + r2 + "; r3 " + r3);
        RandomSet app = new RandomSet();
        Set t = app.randomSet(5, 1, 3);
        Iterator i = t.iterator();
        System.out.println(" randomSet ");
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(" " + i.next());
        }
    }

    public Set<Integer> randomSet(final int high, final int low, final int number){
        if(number > (high - low)){
            throw new RuntimeException("bad high low for number");
        }
        Map<Integer,Integer> rnds = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random ();
        int r1 = 0;
        while(rnds.size() < number){
            r1 = rnd.nextInt(high - 1) + low;
            rnds.put(r1, r1);
        }
        return rnds.keySet();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a student problem, so this won't include much code.

Suppose you have a deck of cards, and you want to deal a poker hand to a player.  What would you do?  You'd take a deck of cards, shuffle it, and deal five cards.  But instead of cards in your problem, you have a list of numbers:

1. Create a `List<Integer>`.
2. Initialize it by adding the integers 1 to 5 to the list.

   - Parameterize this: write a method that takes the size as an argument.
3. Shuffle the list.  Look at the `Collections` class.
4. Take 3 integers from the list and add them to a new list.  Look at what `List.remove(int)` returns.

   - Again, parameterize the method.

Another method that doesn't involve shuffling is this:

1. Create a `List<Integer>`.
2. Initialize it by adding the integers 1 to 5 to the list.
3. Look at the first element. With probability 3/5, use it.
4. Look at the next element. There are either 2 or 3 open slots, and 4 numbers to go. With probability the number of open slots divided by the number of remaining integers, accept this element.
5. Repeat for the next element; there are 1, 2, or 3 open slots, and 3 numbers left to go. With probability 1/3. 2/3, or 3/3, accept this element.

Verify using pen and paper that any integer in the list is chosen with probability 3/5.

Comment: this would not work well if the range of random numbers was very large. like give me 3 unique random number between 1 and 9999999

Comment: True.  The second method could use a for loop instead of a list, or one could use a lazy list.  That's not typical for Java though. Also, I realize that biases in random number generators can hurt.